# How do I move div after its next div

Tags: jquery, html

How do I move a div after its next div.
For instance I have 3 different div sitting here.

```
<div class="div1">Div1</div>
<div class="div2">Div2</div>
<div class="div3">Div3</div>
```

I wan to move first div after the second div. It means `div2` will be first and `div1` will be second. I have bunch of same html format.

I want to execute jquery something like

```
$(".div1").each(function() {
    $(this).appendTo().$(this).after();
});
```

Let me know if this doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

you can get the [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) element, and place it [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

or

you can [.insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) the [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) element

http://jsfiddle.net/kFTc5/1/

```
$(".div1").each(function() {
    var item = $(this);

    //either this:
    item.next().after(item);

    //or this:
    item.insertAfter(item.next());


});
```

Comment: i guess i did have it backwards. i was thinking if `insertAfter()`. thanks!

Comment: Why not simplify it to this?  http://jsfiddle.net/as2s6y4b/

No need for the "each" right?

Answer (score 11):

Here is how you do cut paste operations with DOM in jQuery way.

```
Var temp=  $(“div1”).detach(); //Performs the cut operation
temp.insertAfter(“div2”);  //Does the paste
```

Comment: You don't need to `detach`, just `$('.div1').insertAfter('.div2');​` is sufficient: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/LFqG3/

Comment: I think your answer is the best Mu

Comment: Detach will also copy along all the event handlers attached to that DOM element, not sure if just insertAfter would do, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: no need to detach. if you check, they just move the elements.

Comment: From jQuery official documentation: "The .detach() method is the same as .remove(), except that .detach() keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements.  This method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the DOM at a later time."  

So lets say you have written a code for mousein and mouseout events using jQuery (can be counted as all jQuery data associated) , that handler would behave erratically if you don't use detach. Why do you think that jQuery folks would include a useless method and that too when you have remove() to perform the cut operation alone ?

Comment: I'm not criticizing but `$('.div1').insertAfter('.div2');` preserves the bindings unless I'm missing something: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/LFqG3/1/

Comment: In this case OP doesn't want to insert the removed (or detached) element "at a later time" - the requirement is to move it immediately, and .insertAfter() (and several other methods) will do that - no need for .detach() _for this purpose_.