# How to force divs below right divs

Tags: css, html

six divs - 1 2 3 4 5 6   ....I want div number 2 4 6 to be below divs 1 3 5.   Is that possible? Sorry if my explanation is that good. It's kind of hard. Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/LkGV8/

```
<body>


<div class="contain">

    <div class="square">
    </div>
    <div class="rec01">
    </div>
    <div class="square">
    </div>
    <div class="rec02">
    </div>
    <div class="square">
    </div>
    <div class="rec03">
    </div>

</div>

</body>



  .contain {
    border:1px solid;
    width:639px;
    height:900px;
    background-color:;
    }

    .square {
    width:33%;
    height:50px;
    float:left;
    background-color:grey;
    }

    .rec01 {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    float:right;
    background-color:black;
    }

   .rec02 {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    float:right;
    background-color:black;
    }

    .rec03 {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    float:right;
    background-color:black;
    }
```

(add more details, don't pay attention this.)

Comment: Please include your CSS in the actual post rather than as a comment. You also might want to look into tagging your question properly so that it gets noticed by the right people. Try adding "css" at least, but "html" might help you as well. Also, the HTML you provided does not match the HTML in your fiddle, which one should it be?

Comment: Do you have an image of what you want it to look like?

Comment: Is it not an option to simply rearrange the divs?

Answer (score 1):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/KS2PA/)

Not sure if this is what you mean.

Remove `float` from `.square` and add `display:inline-block` to it

```
.square {
    width:32%;
    height:50px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just shuffle the elements in the markup the way you want them? [You can do it with some jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004801/how-do-i-move-div-after-its-next-div).

```
// not a pretty solution, but should work...
$( ".rec01" ).insertBefore( ".square:eq(0)" );
$( ".rec02" ).insertBefore( ".square:eq(1)" );
$( ".rec03" ).insertBefore( ".square:eq(2)" );
```

Your question needs an image with how you want the final version to look. This answer is assuming you want the elements 2, 4 and 6 below 1, 3 and 5 respectively.

Comment: Really not pretty as is's possible to do purely with css. see below. (:nth-child)

Comment: Both answers have completely different results. This is why an image, or a more specific question would help.

Answer (score 0):

The answer could be: use a grid.

```
<h3>Option 1</h3>
<div class="grid">
    <div>
        <div class="grid">
            <div>1</div>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid">
            <div>4</div>
            <div>5</div>
            <div>6</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<h3>Option 2</h3>
<div class="grid">
    <div>
        <div class="grid">
            <div>1</div>
            <div>3</div>
            <div>5</div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid">
            <div>2</div>
            <div>4</div>
            <div>6</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The css and visual is available on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yAYcx/).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `:nth child` as provided in this [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LkGV8/6/).
As follows:

```
.contain div:nth-child(odd) {
position:relative;
top:0;
}
.contain div:nth-child(even) {
position:relative;
top:220px;
}
```

Comment: Dear downvoter, please explain yourself. He wanted to place every other div under the rest. What's the prob?